# Use Proxy - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, proxy, webrequest

I have a Web Application running on the client server. Since the server where the application is running is an environment closed to the internet, we need to give firewall permissions to use some APIs.

We are trying to use a Proxy for a similar job. There's nothing wrong with Local, but when we run it on the server, we get the error "The basic connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred in sending."

.Net Version = 4.6.1

```
    var proxy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["proxy"];
        var proxyPort = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["proxyPort"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxy)) httpWebRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, Convert.ToInt32(proxyPort));


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(strParameter);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;
        try
        {
            httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Gfycat GetToken Error => " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Please do not post code as image. Please amend your question to include the related piece of code.

Comment: Thx for feedback, edited..